# Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler'

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

Why is my build.gradle.kts file looking like this? This is a fresh Spring Boot project generated with start.spring.io. I already tried invalidate caches / restart, rebuild, resyncing and nothing works. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The IDE's JDK registrations are most likely inaccurate or outdated.
In my case this was in Android Studio and tied to a Toolbox issue. Whatever your case, the principle is the same.

### Option 1: Different JDK

Search for the "Gradle" page settings in Preferences, pick or download a different compatible JDK from the list, then run Gradle sync.

If that works, you know the problem. If you can just stick with the new one, great. If you need to fix the previous JDK (e.g. you're in Android Studio and want the embedded one), you will want to rebuild the JDK table.

### Option 2: Rebuild JDK Table

1. Shut down the IDE
2. Find and delete `jdk.table.xml` from your app's config directory (somewhere in `~/Library/Application Support/` or `%APPDATA%`)
3. Start up the IDE and let it finish indexing.
4. Return to Gradle preferences and specify your preferred JDK

Comment: Hi, Im struggling to get this, and I am encountering the same issue. I have gradle 7.6 on my mac and Java 17 with jenv and I am getting a whole lot of this. How do I switch my gradle JDK ? I didnt know Gradle had a JDK

Comment: It didn't help me

Comment: option 2 worked for me. i also deleted .gradle and .idea (without the shelf) directories before opening android studio

Answer (score 7):

This is what solved it:

1. Delete ~/.gradle/caches
2. Uninstall and Delete ~/Library/Application\ Support/Library/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea
3. Delete <project dir>/.gradle
4. Delete <project dir>/.idea
5. Start IDEA and reimport the project.

Answer (score 0):

I always had this issue in Android studio, but there is an easy way to solve it:

**replace default "Embedded JDK" with a path to the separately downloaded JDK**

For example in Android studio: Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK

After that, `Reload Gradle Project`.

Comment: It didn't help me